# Populating a table by ajax is very slow

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, xhtml

I have written a web service that returns some data as json. To display this in a table I am using the datatables jquery plugin:

```
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
       myTable.fnAddData( [
       "<input name='codeSearched' type='radio' value='"+results[i].ID+"' />",
       "<span id='code_"+results[i].ID+"'>"+ results[i].code+"</>",
       results[i].description ] ,true);
}
```

This javascript seems to kill the browser. (20+ seconds on firefox for just a few thousand rows). I have loaded similar amounts of data into a datatables table before orders of magnitude faster by rendering it server side as an html fragment and inserting directly into the dom.

Can you recommend a way to get the best of both worlds? (I.e, call an ajax web service that serves data in an open structured format, but also parse and render quickly?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: you're displaying THOUSANDS of rows at once? that insane. and using javascript to create a dom structure for that is going to be much much slower than having a server side app only rendering html.

Comment: Not displaying, but yes they need to be in the dom for datatables to paginate and search client side.

Comment: As you said, html fragments are far faster (and simpler), might not be worth the headache...

Comment: Why do you want to do the pagination and search on the client side? Won't it be faster on the server? You could display just the current page of results on the client. If it needs more data, go back to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to get some timing information to see how quickly your call comes back.

There are two ways I do this, one is to use firebug to see how long it takes, and also to put in timing around my call so I can see how long from when I start the call to when I am actually done.

If that is acceptable, then building the table is the problem.

You will want to look at this article to ensure your technique isn't killing you, timewise, as there is a different between using DOM functions and innerHTML.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

The next issue is that if you are trying to fully build the table, you will find that the browser won't show it until you are done, and that can be a killer.

So, what I have done in the past is to build it in pieces. So, I build up perhaps 100 rows, then use `setTimeout` so that the browser can display that, then I build the next batch, until I am done.

This way the user can quickly see the first part of the table, and it should be done before they need the entire table built (such as if they need to look at the bottom row).

How many rows to build at a time is a trade-off between user needs and performance.

Comment: Yeah, I have firebug, the ajax call only takes about 1 second. So with that you think the only way is to rewrite the javascript to render the table in chunks?

Comment: You will want to make certain that your calls to build the table aren't causing you problems, then, as a final step, I found building in chunks was my only real option to avoid waiting many seconds for the table.  Get numbers so you know how much time each part is taking, before you optimize, though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to set the last parameter to "false"? It should run significantly faster, but the user would have to wait until the table is populated.

If it makes it fast enough, you may want to make it a bit more interactive, perhaps you could set the parameter "false", but "true" every 10 or a 100 records to allow redrawing the table.

The reason to fill a list of thousands of radio buttons is beyond me... it doesn't sound like a good User Interface practice, but you must have your reasons.

Good luck!

Luis